# What is the difference between a double and short type in C?

Tags: c, pointers, double, short

I am writing a C code but am not sure when to use a double or a short type when defining a pointer. Can someone explain the difference between the two?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @may14 Pointer is a derived type that is its type depends on the type of the object it points to.

Comment: what's difference between double or short

Comment: [C Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

Comment: What do you mean by "when to use double or short type **when defining a pointer**"? What does the choice of double or short have to do with defining a pointer?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Tell us a bit more. As it stands here the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types):

Short: Short signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−32,767, +32,767] range;[3][4] thus, it is **at least 16 bits in size**. The negative value is −32767 (not −32768) due to the one's-complement and sign-magnitude representations allowed by the standard, though the two's-complement representation is much more common.

Double: Real floating-point type, usually referred to as a double-precision floating-point type. Actual properties unspecified (except minimum limits), however on most systems this is the IEEE 754 **double-precision binary floating-point format**. This format is required by the optional Annex F "IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic".

---

Something to keep in mind, shorts need to be an integer type (No decimal). Doubles are floating type (With decimal).